# How can I convince the internet that my magic is real?

Tags: magic, internet

my name's amàlí and i'm a <strike>hyper</strike> spunky 23 yr old <strike>girl</strike> woman (lol, i guess, idk). i run a youtube channel called AMAzing (get it!?) where i talk about what's going on in my life and the world and draw for people and stuff. well, i can do magic and so i thought i'd share it with my subscribers cuz it's super cool (also fun). but nobody believes me! they all just think its special effects and hyperbole.

i don't edit my own show, i know some nerds who help me out (thx, <3 u guys) cuz i'm more artsy fartsy and kung fu than comp nerd. anyway, i think i need to stop wearing low cut shirts cuz i swear half my subs are there cuz of my pasty 'assets' instead of to actually listen to me.

the point is, how can i get my subs to believe i can do magic?? i can do pretty much anything u can think of (like all those -kineseseses, and psychometry, and teleportation, and stuff). what's my best bet?

thx y'all :) Xs

-amà

---

Do I need to translate? I guess I should translate.

Okay. Here we have a gen-Y YouTube girl (who seems to have a vendetta against capital letters and types like a 12-year old) who wants to share her joy with people - but everyone on the internet is a skeptic (and maybe not even really paying attention). What can she do to be taken seriously and believed? It doesn't seem like she cares about being noticed by the 'wrong people' and is more concerned with the tendency for people to think that everything is a con or a trick.

I have some thoughts myself, but she's already heard me... it's your turn!

-aon

EDIT:

It appears that I need to make an alteration to better explain the question. Here goes:

In a world exactly like our own, the year is 2017, and The Masquerade is in full effect. There are some particular persons, scattered across the globe, who have access to abilities that make Man greedy and the Gods jealous. Suppose that one of these such people was a *genuinely good person* and enjoyed (gasp) *sharing with others*. Those who are part of The Masquerade do not approve of sharing... but! They are curmudgeonly people and wave away mention of this newfangled 'Inter-net' thing. How would such a person bring their abilities into the public eye without the interjection of said curmudgeons? How would one unmask The Masquerade?

Since the question has been posed: What are the limits of this magic?

Let's assume that the sky is the limit. The limitation in this case is not the magic itself, but the intentions of the user. Sure, you could just roll reality up like play-doh and make everyone believe everything you say; but that is *not very nice* and also *really boring*.

Comment: Maybe you should add what kind of magic amàli does.

Comment: Almost forgot: Welcome to worldbuilding.se. Please take a look at the help center and the tour to learn more about the focus of wb.se. Most likely your post will be closed as "off-topic" because it focuses on idea generation and not on World Building. Maybe you can rephrase your question to: In a modern day world, how can one convince the world, that there is magic.

Comment: @AlexandervonWernherr she did say, in her 3rd paragraph.

Comment: @JDługosz For me, this smells story based. But I think one can argue about.

Comment: @AlexandervonWernherr Thanks for the welcome, as well as the suggestion. I'll think about how I can rephrase things. My intention was to use an allegory to create an implicit context for the question rather than explain a complete explicit one. I've seen many "how would X happen" questions and thought this one would fit. If it ends up getting closed, however, I will completely understand.

Comment: Such in-character presentations have inconsistent reception: sometimes they work, sometimes not. In this case, I suspect that nobody enjoys reading the kid’s post; it is completely at odds with the more literate level enjoyed here.

Comment: @AlexandervonWernherr I don't want to get your nose out of joint (you may or may not, be familiar with the phrase), but story based this is not. The heart of the question is actually in the title. Basically, does a person convince others on the internet she has magic powers.

Comment: @a4android No, until now, I didn't know that phrase, but I can handle google ;). In my opinion, it is storybased, because of everything but the title. In your's it is not. WB.SE is democratic, so let the people decide. I'm fine with every decision, just doing my little bit of service.

Comment: If her magic works every time it's really a non-question. Demonstrate it live, to progressively more expert and skeptical audiences. But if her magic works sometimes, and much more often not, then it's an interesting question.

Comment: I don't know if it is possible because you didn't say anything specific about the magic, but if you teach the viewers how to do it... Well, they will believe it. It could also end the world :) Be careful with that :D

Comment: But **why** would some magician want to convince others of the ability? Isn't it enough to conjure up possessions, entertainment, conveniences, love, or money (which takes care of all the aforementioned) in limitless supplies and live a sufficiently public and prodigal life to gain the magician all the fame/notoriety she craves? I mean, with a no-limits magic ability, it's not even problematic to tell the IRS or People Mag "I conjured it all up" when asked about the source of wealth.

Comment: @JDługosz - I think the opening in-character introduction is fine - I have no problem with it.  We very rarely get to see the "voice" behind any particular question, and I welcome this aspect of the question as it helps to form a picture of the world in question and brings context to the answers.

Comment: @fr13d: Exactly.  Convince certain people that your magic is real, and you'll spend the rest of your life (which may not be long, if they decide dissection will reveal the srcret) in a secret government/industrial lab.  Instead, you become a stage magician, with illusions so good that you're soon a Las Vegas headline act.  Fame & fortune follow, and no worries about the IRS wondering how you came by all that undeclared income :-)

Comment: @fr13d As to why, good question. I think many people in that situation *wouldn't* want to convince anyone. However, I do think there would be some that would want to share their gift. If I could draw photorealistic art, but every time I posted it to an art website I was rebuked for posting photographs that I ran though an art filter, I would want to find a way to prove I actually drew them (in this case, by making a video of the process).

Comment: lol is SO 2000. 23 year olds tend to ha ha not lol...http://www.theverge.com/2015/8/10/9125797/haha-lol-or-hehe-facebook

Comment: @ErinThursby Well pointed out. I, myself, tend to heh, HAH, haha, or AHAHAHAHahahhehehe....*cough* when writing my laughter. Although, I do admit to the sparse, well-timed lol when it is appropriate :>

Comment: This question came up for review to reopen. There's a good kernel here, but I'm going to let it stay closed for now because it really is hard to parse out the core concept. BUT--- I suggest this question get moved to the Sandbox where it can be revised by the community until it is in a more compact and directly answerable form. http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/635/sandbox-for-proposed-questions

Comment: Don’t *change the question* after it has been answered!  “how do I expose the conspiracy” and “what are the limits” are very different from what you asked originally.  And don’t put multiple separate questions in one post.  You might look at the **sandbox** topic on [meta] to help proof your thoughts before posting “for real”.

Comment: @JDługosz My apologies for stepping on any proverbial toes. First, I would like to point out that I did not ask "what are the limits" I **responded** to that question as it had been posed by others. Second, The Masquerade is not a conspiracy. It's a secret. I believe that making a secret *known to the public* was inherent in my original question. Third, I was not aware of the 'sandbox topic' and will certainly take it into account for future questions, thank you for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: I am willing to vote to reopen - the question is now on-topic - but it's less clear what you're asking now. The "Masquerade" information is **extremely** relevant now, and should be emphasized toward the beginning of the question. It looks like you're asking two different things - "how to pretend you can do magic" and "how to prove you can do magic". If you establish the setting - and her reality - earlier in the question so that it's clear I will vote to reopen.

Comment: @Zxyrra I'll take a look at how I can reword things. I only ever intended for the latter question you mentioned and not the former but I suppose that's unclear. Thank you for the comment!

Comment: It seems out of character that she'd know a word like “hyperbole” and furthermore spell it correctly.

Comment: @JDługosz It would seem so, wouldn't it. However, this character is one I have extremely well developed and it was an intentional word choice. I actually spent a silly amount of time writing that intro and making sure the grammar was all the way it should be. Well noticed, though :)

Answer (score 27):

Easy: call the [JREF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Randi_Educational_Foundation) and win the Randi Prize.  Proving supernatural claims to scientific standards is what this is *for* (and the million dollars is nice, too).

Anything you simply demonstrate to your followers will wind up on [Captain Disillusion](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCEOXxzW2vU0P-0THehuIIeg) etc. and be presumed to be a video hoax.

---

In real life, the Randi challenge has been discontinued. There are still [others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_prizes_for_evidence_of_the_paranormal), but best drama would be to involve a venerable character that can give credible authority. So make up your own character based on Randi, set it in the recent past, have the challenge still exist in your universe, or pass *other* tests and then have the retired venerable authority consult to design and officiate over ultimate high-publicity testing.  The real James Randi is pushing 90.

In your story, I can imagine that first the youtube community of video SFX variously analyses and duplicates her video feats. Then she has some of *those people* shoot the video as she performs.  Then the street magic group duplicate it, claiming they know how it was done (each inventing his own way).  Only after repeated rounds of this does she learn how scientific method is the real answer, and that scientists are fooled by magicians so *finally* finds the niche represented by Randi etc.  Being a kid<sup>※</sup> works out well as it makes it more beleivable that she didn’t already know some of those things, and the case of past hign-profile (fake) psycics.

---

※ OK, 23 is not exactly a kid… it reads more like an early teen ager.  Even so, the last round of John Edwards, Sylvia Browne, et al. would be before she payed attention to such TV shows.

Comment: This is likely going to be what a lot of the commenters on her video will suggest as well, so it shouldn't be hard for her to figure out.

Comment: Various skeptics organizations could rise to the challenge of trying to debunk her magic. Their failure is her success. Also, she work her way through the list of paranormal prizes.

Comment: But don't you know: Randi has a secret dark motive: http://rationalfiction.io/story/the-randi-prize

Answer (score 6):

## If you don't personally experience it, it's nothing more than hearsay

It's the internet, so some people are going to believe anything - just like those videos you seen about people doing unfeasible things with table tennis balls.

To get things real, you need to make real things happen, for all of your viewers.

Some simple (and non harmful) things to do would be:

- ask your viewers to hold something in their hand and then move it to their other hand
- make an origami model out of a piece of paper on the viewer's desk
- change the ring-tone on their phone to the [My Little Pony](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZcBNxuKZyN4) theme tune

**For magic to be real, it needs to be actually experienced by the viewer**, otherwise it's just stuff that people see on their computer and therefore open to scepticism.

Answer (score 4):

> Beware of false prophets, which come to you in sheep's clothing, but
>   inwardly they are ravening wolves. Ye shall know them by their
>   fruits. Do men gather grapes of thorns, or figs of thistles? Even so
>   every good tree bringeth forth good fruit; but a corrupt tree bringeth
>   forth evil fruit. A good tree cannot bring forth evil fruit, neither
>   can a corrupt tree bring forth good fruit. Every tree that bringeth
>   not forth good fruit is hewn down, and cast into the fire. Wherefore
>   by their fruits ye shall know them.

Translated (and *totally* not revenge for making me read that *in character* text) :

People will believe in magic if it produces magical results. Healing the sick is the traditional one used by various holy men. Obviously this depends on what kind of magic the person has, but any magic worth calling magic should have *some* utility. Just go ahead and use it effectively and openly. The word will get around very fast.

Unless your power works over the internet (in which case you have no problem), the internet is simply a channel for doing public relations and publicity for whatever you actually do. Use of powers and proving their reality is something you do live and direct as needed to produce whatever results it is you want.

Comment: Nice! Thank you for directing your frustration at reading the intro into writing what may or may not be (but looks like) a Bible quote! My curiosity would be how you might manage these sorts of things over the internet. Just searching YouTube for 'telekinesis' gives you all sorts of people using their 'powers' openly, and yet, they are scoffed at and their videos torn apart to find rendering artifacts.

Comment: @aonphléacs I think he means in real life applications: like for charity, for example.

Answer (score 3):

## Live performance.

No matter how many "Fake!" comments there are, there will still be some people believe in what they see and want to see it live.

So, the next step is going into public. Do magic without any chance for someone to say "Cheat!" without safeguards. Standing in the middle of a public space, wearing a bikini (to avoid any hidden tools), holding a ball of fire in the hands would be a good start or levitate random people or things.

Comment: Be careful of what public space you're standing in. Certain locations will fine you for wearing a bikini in a public space, others will fine you and your viewers for forming too big groups in public, others will arrest you for reckless endangerment when you start juggling fire or levitating random people.

Answer (score 2):

**Predict the future! Correctly, many times, and on events with enough impact.**

This cannot be faked with special effects (or ordinary effects, for that matter!). No matter how hard people cry "fake!", it won't take long until even the most adamant skeptics have no choice but to admit that they cannot rationally explain how you are right time and again with your predictions. Once your magical girl starts getting enough publicity, she could start to make self-fulfilling prophecies too, to show people that she can predict not only future possibilities but unavoidable destinies.

Comment: I'd start with lottery numbers.  Someone who claims foresight and wins the PowerBall lottery 10 times in a row would have me convinced.

Comment: @Jym I claim the lottery was rigged or she otherwise cheated.

Comment: Better do it in a dozen or so lotteries at once then, multiple times. And certainly should not leave it to lotteries only. Of course, if one is dogmatic enough, then there really is no way of convincing them of magic no matter what.