# Ways to prove magic to the entire modern world?

Tags: society, magic

To set up my question, let's say there exists a closed magical society who has kept quiet that magic exists up until the late 2010s. I need some way to create a situation where:

1. Magic is revealed to the world at large such as on live tv. Or, at least rapidly spread within a few days with mass hysteria.
2. There is little to no doubt that current levels of science cannot explain the level of split second reality warping seen, thus forcing the modern world to come to terms there exists a force that was hidden from them.

The magic system for this question would be capable of mind reading, instant teleportation, and spells for attack and defence. It is a force that can be used to override laws of nature (to greater degrees depending on the level of determination/emotion put into the desired action). They can alter objects around them and people as well.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding! If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. We had a very similar question some time ago. I would even go as far as to call it a duplicate: [How can I convince the internet that my magic is real?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/69716/28789). It was closed as off-topic because it was aimed at writing a story about a person the author created, which would be off-topic, but there were some answers that might help you. Have fun on the site!

Comment: The question is... Do you want this to be an accident? Or does the secret society want to go public with a bang?

Comment: Why not use said magic to make the world get convinced?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convince the internet that my magic is real?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/69716/how-can-i-convince-the-internet-that-my-magic-is-real)

Answer (score 3):

How big, flashy, and intimidating do you want your reveal to be, and how powerful an effect can you manage?  Co-opt a major sporting event (the Super Bowl, the Opening Ceremony of the Olympics, etc.) and teleport a stadium full of people a couple miles away.  Levitate a skyscraper.  Trigger simultaneous volcanic eruptions around the world.  Carve a glyph on the moon.  Create a free-standing portal between Times Square and downtown Tokyo.

For something a bit lower-key, teleport into the keynote speech of a major physics conference, say "Hi", and watch everyone's heads collectively implode.

Comment: Making any show during events which thrive on shows and illusions is counter-productive to say the least. Have you actually watched Olympic opening ceremonies? Flying skyscraper would count as maybe 5th most impressive thing.

Comment: I suppose I phrased things poorly.  I was suggesting teleporting the whole stadium.  That would be a bit much even for opening ceremonies standards.

Answer (score 3):

Start a courier company. Offer to transport any item from anywhere in the world to anywhere else in the world for a substantial fee. They go on the website, input start, destination, weight, etc. You teleport to them. Take the package. Teleport to destination. Deliver package.

That would become news very fast.

Not to mention get a lot of interest from customs officials and drug smugglers. I hope you're bullet proof.

Don't even try to "prove magic". Just start doing it in public, let other people start asking the obvious questions like "how does Instaparcel get my package from London to Australia in 30 seconds"?

Answer (score 2):

For magic to be revealed and accepted, you would need:

- A good amount of **influence**, as already stated by Bwrites, since you need a vast majority of the public informed that *something unexplainable* can happen in the world and *magic may as well be real.* This is easily done throught coverage by the social (and the traditional) media.
- Support from the **scientific** community. Funnily enough, you need some kind of authority to step up and say "allright, we don't understand how those people can shoot fireballs out of their eyes; we may have missed something."
- **Persistent and undeniable effort** to make things clear to the public. It is unclear how the governments would react at the notion that a small group of individuals is capable of doing the impossible. Either to preserve stability and avoid chaos in the population, or for darker plans, the higher-up of every nation could try to cover up "magical incidents". I noticed just now that you actually want mass hysteria to be generated, but still the point holds. Your mages have to be recognized as mages, and not perceived, lets say, as terrorist bombers.
- **Mages must agree**: of course if your magical society has been secret until 2010, there must be good reasons. You need the majority of your mages favorable to going out in the open; if that's not the case, mages against can work against the revelation.

The best thing you can play around with is teleportation. One teleportation mage could carry the news in the whole globe, interrupting live transmissions as they are being streamed. He should be clearly recognizable, maybe carrying some symbol (let's say a red "x" on his shirt for convenience).

Better still is if you can provide the wide public with a tight timeline of his apparitions: let's say your magic society is on social media or on a media with some audience. 
Their spokesman could just say: "One of our magicians is going to teleport in all the countries, live. Here's a list of the scheduled times of his apparitions". Following the list, people could see the same person materializing in and out of thin-air - that's pretty difficult to explain. The only con is that teleportation magic in your world must be convenient enough for this to work (e.g.: it doesn't take hours for a single jump, but mere seconds or minutes).

Other good spells could be levitation, telekinesis or gravity-bending, shielding of one person or area (imagine seeing something survive being shot in the face without harm) and so on. The only one you mentioned that doesn't play well is mind reading, since it's rather difficult to prove.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding *Liquid*! If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

Convince [James Randi Educational Foundation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Randi_Educational_Foundation) to reinstate [One Million Dollar Paranormal Challenge](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Million_Dollar_Paranormal_Challenge) and then, go win it. James Randi is a former stage magician, currently a prominent skeptic and debunker. Getting his foundation to admit that something is on, will make every skeptic take you seriously. After dozen or so shows in controlled environment, it will be proven that something unusual is happening. It will be awhile before general populace is convinced, but professional skeptics should already be on your side, and science will scramble to analyze the phenomenon.

Comment: Damn you were 4 seconds faster

Answer (score 0):

### Social Media

With enough influence, (and money) this magical society can make themselves viral. Imagine a single funny video can get thousands of views, magic tricks gaining millions of views, then what more with real magic?

Even if people don't believe at first, social media promotion will be spreading like wild-fire anyway. If a video is real or not, people don't care, they share it anyway. And if this magical society gets enough attention, the Media will inevitably contact them, feature them on TV, etc. It will be a domino effect and their fame cannot be stopped. And of course, proving real magic to the masses will be inevitable sooner or later.

Comment: This is more of a way to promote, not to prove.

Comment: But how can you prove *to the world* if you are not famous? I think when you promote, the act to prove will closely follow since skeptics will naturally debunk them. If they cannot be debunked, then what else will be revealed, but the truth?

Comment: The problem with the social media promotion approach might possibly be that everyone believes its a hoax or nice animation anyways. For real proof you would have to turn to several respected and established media agencies (from all around the globe: western world - Arabian - Russian - Chinese - Japanese - South American networks) and have at least one scientific expert invited as well to provide an educated opinion that science cannot explain the magical phenomenon.

Comment: Being active in some skeptic groups, etc. I see dozens of videos of UFOs, Chemtrails, etc. in social feed (for the laughs). So, there already are many social media "proofs" of such things. Still, no sane person believes in them, which means that social media is not the best way for such a thing, because people will call it a hoax (and why shouldn't they? Every proof of magic til this point WAS a hoax).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is broad, but I can't say it's too broad for my taste. Basically you're asking how to get everyone to notice an occurrence and believe that it's supernatural. Notability and believability.

**Do a cool mass magic trick.**

- Tell everyone simultaneously - Professor Xavier mind-spoke to every person in the world in X-men 2016.
- You can instantly cure a serious illness for everyone in the world/state/area.
- Drastically change the weather / appearance of the sky/sun/something that everyone can see.
- Turn everyone into a chicken (but, you'll turn us back, right?)
- and so on and so forth, so long as the two requirements are satisfied.

In most stories, people have a hard time keeping their magic a secret. This can be a lot of fun :-)

[Now that scientists have invented magic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UnYPaENQVDc)